# JQuery Plugin for dropdown form + search like JIRA

Tags: jquery, forms, jira

I'm searching for a JQuery plugin that will have similar functionality to JIRA's dropdown.

Basically a button that when clicked, drops down with a form with checkboxes or radio buttons. A search filter up the top is needed, and also a way to order the checkboxes on the fly by placing the ticked checkboxes at the top of the form upon opening the form.

[image]

I can't find any plugin that will do this for me.. it's not particularly difficult to build, but if there's already an implementation of this out there, I'd rather use that.

Answer (score 0):

On the following link you'll find a whole bunch of dropdowns like that:

http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-multiselect-plugin/

There are even more of them here:

http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/multiple-select

I haven't tested them but they look like what you are looking for.